# Certbot with Tomcat9 (linode) Ubuntu 19.4

Tags: tomcat9, certbot

i've set up the https on apache http server (port 80) along with webmin (port 10000) using let's encrypt. i've installed tomcat9 on the same server and it's listening to port 8080 (http). tomcat9 server also works fine. i am trying to set up the https for tomcat9. i've copied cert1.pem, chain1.pem, and privkey.pem from /etc/letsencrypt/archive/{domain.com} folder into /etc/tomcat9 folder. Also updated server.xml by uncommenting "connector port="8443" section and put the locations of the pem files on the certificate section. i've restarted the tomcat9 service. When i go to http://example.com:8080, it shows the tomcat webpage. if i do https://example.com:8080 or https://example.com:8443, i get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. iptable -L -n -v shows the port 8443 to accept. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working due to spelling mistake in server.xml.  Instead of privkey.pem, i had key.pem.   it's working now.